# Can not make Detailview render data

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hello guys I'm new with Django class based views, I'm learning.

What am I doing wrong ?
It suppose to render ids but it does not

Url.py

```
path('v/<int:pk>', V.as_view(), name='v'),
```

views.py

```
class V(DetailView):
    model = Empresa
    template_name = 'detalle.html'
```

.html

```
{%for x in empresa_list%}

{{x.NombreEmpresa}}

{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis is a `DetailView`, hence it passes the single object as `object` or `empresa`. You thus render this with:

```
{{ object.NombreEmpresa }}
```

and thus *without* a `{% for … %}` loop.